# How to fix Consumer and Channel related Error in andengine?

Tags: android, andengine

What does this Error mean?

```
08-08 10:10:39.203: ERROR/InputDispatcher(60): channel '406c6df0 org.bg.demo/org.bg.demo.BgDemoActivity (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x8

08-08 10:10:39.203: ERROR/InputDispatcher(60): channel '406c6df0 org.bg.demo/org.bg.demo.BgDemoActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
```

Answer (score 0):

From the two error lines that you have I can only guess to what your problem might be. So my guess is that you are starting a `thread` twice. See if you have two `start()` for the same `thread`.

See if that is the problem. If you want a better guess post your whole `logCat` error log.

Comment: 08-08 10:55:48.381: ERROR/logwrapper(161): executing /system/bin/tc failed: No such file or directory
08-08 10:55:48.391: ERROR/logwrapper(162): executing /system/bin/tc failed: No such file or directory
08-08 11:01:23.186: ERROR/InputDispatcher(60): channel '40766770 org.bg.demo/org.bg.demo.BgDemoActivity (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x8
08-08 11:01:23.186: ERROR/InputDispatcher(60): channel '40766770 org.bg.demo/org.bg.demo.BgDemoActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!

Comment: Can you edit your question and add your code and the complete logCat.